# Returning a view with async keyword

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are some code samples where I show some code like below.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User user)
 {
      ///Logic to add user
      return View();
 }
```

Is this a good practice to return a view with async action result method as view result it self-does not support async.

I checked in normal scenarios it works perfectly fine but what are the scenarios where it might fail or create problems.

Comment: It looks like Microsoft actually has some official documentation on this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: You can return a view with empty model with `async` marked controller method as long as your processing logic includes an operation with `await` keyword.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The use of `async` and `await` is a good practice to make your web application scalable, said MSDN (if I remember correctly :)). Basically, it helps utilizing your thread pool so that 1 thread does **not necessarily** to be allocated to handle **only 1** request. Suppose that you have this action:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(User user)
 {
      ///Logic to add user
      return await Task.Run(() => View());
 }
```

it's being said that while waiting for the async method to be completed, the thread will be available to be allocated for another work item (e.g another action marked as async) in the .NET run-time thread-pool global queue. This makes the number of threads can be less than the number of requests need handling.

The `async` modifier is marked to tell .NET run-time that this is a work item that can be applied mechanism mentioned above. Without `await` something, it doesn't help much (if we don't want to say "nothing") in terms of performance or resource optimization.

For proof of concept, I played with following actions in my `HomeController`:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> FineGrained()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => {
            return Json(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        });
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> CoarseGrained()
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () => {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            return Json(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        });
    }
```

and this is the jquery script to test the thread utilization:

```
        $.when(
            $.getJSON('/Home/FineGrained'),
            $.getJSON('/Home/CoarseGrained'),
            $.getJSON('/Home/FineGrained'),
            $.getJSON('/Home/FineGrained'),
            $.getJSON('/Home/FineGrained')
        ).done(function (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) {
            console.log(v1[0]);
            console.log(v2[0]);
            console.log(v3[0]);
            console.log(v4[0]);
            console.log(v5[0]);
        });
```

One of many results I got:
30
25
30
30
25

I refreshed the page containing the test script several times and always got repeat thread id. It's fair enough to prove the theory.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. The whole point of async/await is that a thread doesn't have to wait for an I/O operation to complete and that it is free to go back to the threadpool to handle other incoming requests. With thousands of requests/sec, this can unburden your server quite a bit. Remember that every thread has its own stack and thus takes up at least 1MB of memory. 1000 requests = 1000 threads = at least 1000MB RAM occupied. Point being, using `Task.Run()` creates a new thread, so the whole resource-saving advantage is gone.

Comment: @J.P.tenBerge, in terms of Task Inlining of Task Scheduler, using `Task.Run()` does not necessarily create a new thread "as it prevents the need for an additional Thread by utilizing the existing Thread which would have blocked".

And in terms of Work Stealing, "no threads are sitting idle while others still have work in their queues". It's really an utilization on resources.