# Is a return ViewAsync in MVC an advantage and why doesn't it exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await

I hope this is still on-topic. In this post here I saw how to create an `await ViewAsync()`:
[Returning a view with async keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227745/returning-a-view-with-async-keyword)

So my consideration was: okay, I want to make my application use multithreading, let's make a `BaseController` that contains those methods for `ViewAsync`:

just a part of it:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [NonAction]
    public virtual async Task<ViewResult> ViewAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => this.View(null));
    }

    [NonAction]
    public virtual async Task<ViewResult> ViewAsync(string viewName)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => this.View(viewName, this.ViewData.Model));
    }

    // the other implementations....
}
```

now I could always call like this in the inheriting class:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
{
    // maybe we need to do something here, maybe not

    return await ViewAsync(new DoSomethingObject());
}
```

imho, my advantage/target is performance since I always can use multithreading now.

Am I right with my consideration? 
In the post, a comment to an answer started with `I wouldn't do this`. But there aren't many votes/comments/answers.. Where are risks or disadvantages of such an implementation? And maybe, why doesn't `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` come with the method `ViewAsync`?

Comment: A `View` is just a class that concatenates strings. There's no reason for making them `async` as they are supposed to be lightweight, easily processed. Your example creates Thread Pool threads just for this, which is way too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any web app already uses multithreading. When a request comes in, a thread from the thread pool handles it. Your app already handles multiple requests at the same time, without you using `Task.Run`.

Async/await stuff is useful so that you don't block threads from the thread pool while you wait for async operations to complete (like querying a DB).
Starting new tasks `Task.Run` on the default thread pool is pretty much useless, **unless** you are doing some CPU intensive work. Let's say you have an endpoint that calculates the prime numbers up to n on each request, in that case you could delegate a new task on the default thread pool that returns the prime numbers, and have a view that renders them to some html.

Rendering a view has nothing asynchronous about it, so a ViewAsync is not needed. Preparing the data for a view probably is async, but the rendering is not. Also, having a `ViewAsync` would probably over complicate the template syntax.

Comment: So in conclusion, this would only make sense when my view does something special that needs a lot CPU?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger well, views should only render data to html... It makes sense to start new tasks when the data you need to render needs a lot of CPU. The actual rendering part should never take that much CPU.

Comment: You should pretty much *never* use `Task.Run` in a web application context. A web server has a "max requests", which is really just how many threads it can spawn in a process. Using `Task.Run` takes an additional thread from the pool, actually lowering your overall server throughput. `Task.Run` is really for moving stuff off the default thread in native apps (desktop, mobile) where you have a main UI thread that should never be blocked.