# Is there a way to reduce time to load cshtml view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My application is in asp.net-mvc and i return pages this way :

```
[AuthorizedFunctionalities(Functionalities = "Missions_R")] 
public ViewResult Missions()
{
    return View("~/Views/Mission/Missions.cshtml");
}
```

Although I directly return a cshtml page, there is at least 1 sec before the client receives the actual html (seen with devtools -> network on browser). In this page I then call an ajax which loads data in about 500ms.
How come the loading of the page without any call to my DB can be longer than the call where I do requests on my DB ?

Is there a way to reduce this time ? Or to track if there is additional calls that might slow the request ?

Comment: What do you think about making method async?

Comment: Try also to set this :  `<compilation debug="false"></compilation>`  in your App/Web.config

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have debug=false attribute in compilation in my App/Web.config... How can I make a method that returns only a view async ?

Comment: I believe they explained it properly in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227745/returning-a-view-with-async-keyword